# InvalidTokenException for "unsecured" routes in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Since I have updated Spring Boot Version to 2.6.7 I get logs that the way I define unsecured routes is not recommended anymore.

Log message:

```
You are asking Spring Security to ignore Ant [pattern='/actuator/**']. This is not recommended -- please use permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead.
```

The way I was describing the config that Spring Security has to ignore these patterns was done by defining a WebSecurityConfiguration and ignoring those routes. What happens in this case is, that the whole security chain is skipped and the above mentioned logs are written. It's okay for me, but not for Spring ;).

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                       "/actuator/**"
                );
    }
}
```

When defining these route as part of the httpSecurity as mentioned in the log. The problem occurs that an expired/invalid token cause an error (401 unauthorized) as well for unsecured routes like `/actuator/health`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Getter
    private String[] unsecuredPathList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        this.unsecuredPathList = new String[] {
                "/actuator/**"};
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(new CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resourceServer) throws Exception {
        resourceServer.tokenStore(jwtTokenStore());
        resourceServer.tokenExtractor(new SessionCookieTokenExtractor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .anonymous()
            .authorities("ANONYMOUS")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(unsecuredPathList)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
}
```

The goal I want to reach is:
For an unsecure resource the token will not be evaluated/the result is ignored and there is no 401-Unauthorized-Error.

Is there anything I can do in httpSecurity?
Or is there any other recommended way to reach that goal?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you send an expired/invalid token? In this case you should always get an 401. To ignore it seems no good way for security.

Comment: please motivate why you are using `EnableResourceServer` annotation which is in maintenance mode/deprecated instead of implementing the handling of JWTs in the way that spring security recommends in their documentation

Answer (score -1):

There is a group of methods in `HttpSecurity` class, which allows you to apply defined security rules only to specific paths, and thus create different security filter chains with different rules for different urls.

For example, you can exclude some urls like this:

```
// convert your String array into a List of RequestMatcher
List<RequestMatcher> excludedPathMatchers = Arrays.stream(unsecuredPathList)
                .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

// configure HttpSecurity to apply filter chain only on paths, that don't match any of the excluded paths
http.requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(excludedPathMatchers)));
```

Or you can write something like this, if you have only 1 unsecured endpoint:

```
http.requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_url/**")));
```